# My mongos server crashes,Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault) Mongo DB v3.4.16 on SUSE 11 SP4

Tags: mongodb

I am using SUSE 11 SP4_64. And at time of starting mongos , getting FATAL error "Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault)",I tried different versions of mongodb including 3.4.16 and 4.0.2，all fails.Following is the logs took from mongos'log:

```
2020-06-17T17:33:33.838+0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Connecting to 192.168.129.133:36001
2020-06-17T17:33:33.839+0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Successfully connected to 192.168.129.133:36001, took 1ms (3 connections now open to 192.168.129.133:36001)
2020-06-17T17:33:34.042+0800 W SHARDING [replSetDistLockPinger] pinging failed for distributed lock pinger :: caused by :: LockStateChangeFailed: findAndModify query predicate didn't match any lock document
2020-06-17T17:33:34.042+0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Connecting to 192.168.129.134:36001
2020-06-17T17:33:34.043+0800 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-ShardRegistry-0] Successfully connected to 192.168.129.134:36001, took 1ms (1 connections now open to 192.168.129.134:36001)
2020-06-17T17:33:34.064+0800 I FTDC     [mongosMain] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/mongodb/data/mongos/log/mongos.diagnostic.data'
2020-06-17T17:33:34.065+0800 I NETWORK  [thread2] waiting for connections on port 35001
2020-06-17T17:33:34.066+0800 F -        [Uptime reporter] Invalid access at address: 0x3
2020-06-17T17:33:34.069+0800 F -        [Uptime reporter] Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).

 0x7f22482b4cf1 0x7f22482b3f09 0x7f22482b4576 0x7f22469fda50 0x7f223d806e7d 0x7f223d80716d 0x7f223d807432 0x7f223da18c5d 0x7f2246727606 0x7f224672aad1 0x7f2248260d82 0x7f22481e6522 0x7f22486a0660 0x7f22469f59dd 0x7f224673f09d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"7F22476E7000","o":"BCDCF1","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"7F22476E7000","o":"BCCF09"},{"b":"7F22476E7000","o":"BCD576"},{"b":"7F22469EE000","o":"FA50"},{"b":"7F223D7FF000","o":"7E7D","s":"__libc_res_nquery"},{"b":"7F223D7FF000","o":"816D"},{"b":"7F223D7FF000","o":"8432","s":"__libc_res_nsearch"},{"b":"7F223DA16000","o":"2C5D","s":"_nss_dns_gethostbyname4_r"},{"b":"7F2246663000","o":"C4606"},{"b":"7F2246663000","o":"C7AD1","s":"getaddrinfo"},{"b":"7F22476E7000","o":"B79D82","s":"_ZN5mongo12getHostFQDNsENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS_28HostnameCanonicalizationModeE"},{"b":"7F22476E7000","o":"AFF522"},{"b":"7F22476E7000","o":"FB9660"},{"b":"7F22469EE000","o":"79DD"},{"b":"7F2246663000","o":"DC09D","s":"clone"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.4.16", "gitVersion" : "0d6a9242c11b99ddadcfb6e86a850b6ba487530a", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "3.0.101-63-default", "version" : "#1 SMP Tue Jun 23 16:02:31 UTC 2015 (4b89d0c)", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "7F22476E7000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D9AB32A22CFB57BF4F1D38933757EAC3D858C56E" }, { "b" : "7FFC5E0C3000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BBBF6FC4D5118F533262E22CF89C218B14564380" }, { "b" : "7F22472A9000", "path" : "/lib64/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4CA1D0FD328D17244B44C85CBCDC6F247DEAC7EB" }, { "b" : "7F22470A5000", "path" : "/lib64/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "51E0A99A866D4988577F759637E08A91067C1C01" }, { "b" : "7F2246E22000", "path" : "/lib64/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "542B92D95DAE4A4EDCFCB5BE575EB490A560195B" }, { "b" : "7F2246C0B000", "path" : "/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "2A112A7A6EC893B71505222AF6AFE8AD5589B438" }, { "b" : "7F22469EE000", "path" : "/lib64/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CC1ACAE7B917597BE9495DCD1E019D86BCD7E38F" }, { "b" : "7F2246663000", "path" : "/lib64/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "68D6792613BAF23FE38A18E3E5126A2943313308" }, { "b" : "7F22474C4000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "2586B3A5C2F7A71E0012254B4412E650437C0DE9" } ] }}
 mongos(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x7f22482b4cf1]
 mongos(+0xBCCF09) [0x7f22482b3f09]
 mongos(+0xBCD576) [0x7f22482b4576]
 libpthread.so.0(+0xFA50) [0x7f22469fda50]
 libresolv.so.2(__libc_res_nquery+0x4DD) [0x7f223d806e7d]
 libresolv.so.2(+0x816D) [0x7f223d80716d]
 libresolv.so.2(__libc_res_nsearch+0x1E2) [0x7f223d807432]
 libnss_dns.so.2(_nss_dns_gethostbyname4_r+0xED) [0x7f223da18c5d]
 libc.so.6(+0xC4606) [0x7f2246727606]
 libc.so.6(getaddrinfo+0x1C1) [0x7f224672aad1]
 mongos(_ZN5mongo12getHostFQDNsENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS_28HostnameCanonicalizationModeE+0xD2) [0x7f2248260d82]
 mongos(+0xAFF522) [0x7f22481e6522]
 mongos(+0xFB9660) [0x7f22486a0660]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x79DD) [0x7f22469f59dd]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7f224673f09d]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

I'm sure my config service has started successfully，Looking forward to your reply and thank you

Comment: Update to 3.4.24, if the crash still happens you can report it at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER.